# Combining two SQL select statements takes 30 to 40 minutes to get executed

Tags: sql

RDBMS - MS SQL

How can I combine these two SQL select queries into one and get them executed quicly:

### Query 1

```
select 
VVO.VV_CODE, 
V.Vessel_name,                       
VVO.Arrival_date, 
isnull(IGM.VIR_NO,'NULL') as VIR_NO,
isnull(VVO.TERMINAL_CODE,'NULL') as TERMINAL_CODE
from Vessel_voyage VVO, Vessel V, IGM 
where V.Vessel_code = substring(VVO.VV_CODE,1,3) and VVO.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
```

### Query 2

```
select
BLD.BL_NO,                          
isnull(BLD.Parent_BL,'NULL') as Parent_BL,  
BLD.Consignee_Description,
DO.DO_Issue_Date,                   
CA.CAgent_Name,                     
BLC.Container_No ,                  
CS.Container_Size_Description           
from BL_DATA BLD, CAgent CA, Delivery_Order DO, BL_Container BLC, Container_Size CS 
where BLD.BL_NO = DO.BL_NO and DO.CAgent_Code = CA.CAgent_Code and BLD.BL_NO = BLC.BL_NO and BLC.Container_Size_Code = CS.Container_Size_Code
```

Executing these select queries individually, they get executed within seconds.

But making them into a single select query, they take around 30 to 40 minutes to get executed.

This is what I tried:

```
select 
VVO.VV_CODE, 
V.Vessel_name,                       
VVO.Arrival_date, 
isnull(IGM.VIR_NO,'NULL') as VIR_NO,
isnull(VVO.TERMINAL_CODE,'NULL') as TERMINAL_CODE,
BLD.BL_NO,                          
isnull(BLD.Parent_BL,'NULL') as Parent_BL,  
BLD.Consignee_Description,
DO.DO_Issue_Date,                   
CA.CAgent_Name,                     
BLC.Container_No ,                  
CS.Container_Size_Description       
from Vessel_voyage VVO, Vessel V, IGM ,BL_DATA BLD, CAgent CA, Delivery_Order DO, BL_Container BLC, Container_Size CS 
where V.Vessel_code = substring(VVO.VV_CODE,1,3) and VVO.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE and BLD.BL_NO = DO.BL_NO and DO.CAgent_Code = CA.CAgent_Code and BLD.BL_NO = BLC.BL_NO and BLC.Container_Size_Code = CS.Container_Size_Code
```

Comment: The two queries seem to share no obvious relation / output, could you be more explicit on how you you are putting them together. The joins in the query would benefit from converting to ANSI joins to make them more readable.

Comment: Have edited the content, kindly check it @Andrew

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: We are using MS SQL

Comment: one option in MS SQL Server could be to create temp tables for both resultsets and then join these results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the query using ANSI style joins would make it easier to read - so I've done exactly that. It also helps spot where there are problems within the join logic.

Re-writing the joins I get to this :

```
from Vessel_voyage VVO
inner join Vessel V on V.Vessel_code = substring(VVO.VV_CODE,1,3)
inner join IGM on VVO.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
inner join BL_DATA BLD on BLD.BL_NO = DO.BL_NO
inner join CAgent CA
inner join Delivery_Order DO on DO.CAgent_Code = CA.CAgent_Code
inner join BL_Container BLC on BLD.BL_NO = BLC.BL_NO
inner join Container_Size CS on BLC.Container_Size_Code = CS.Container_Size_Code
```

I could move around the DO to CA join predicate but ultimately I have 8 tables being joined, but only 6 predicates joining them - net result is that it is cartesian'ing in one of the tables which is likely to give incorrect results, but most certainly will cause a performance degradation.

If you use this style of join I suspect you will be able to fix it very easily.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew